# Why doesn't my code write to output file?

Tags: c++, fstream

I wrote the following code for a math problem and it won't write into the output file "coada2.out".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0, x, y, z;

    ifstream file_in("coada2.in");
    file_in >> x >> y >> z;
    file_in.close();

    ofstream file_out;
    file_out.open ("coada2.out"); 
    sum=x+2;
    if((y+1 || z+1) == sum) {
        file_out << sum;
        file_out.close();
    }
    else{
        cout<<"-1";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if((y+1 || z+1) == sum) {` is quite strange to me. It will not do what you want.

Comment: Lots of details/information is missing from this question. Like; What operating system are you using? What compiler are you using? What C++ language standard version are you using? What errors are you getting?

Comment: You can write to the file of `z` and `y` are both `-1` and `x` is `-2`. In that case (-1+1 || -1 +1 ) will be false and this false which will equal sum because its 0.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

```
if((y+1 || z+1) == sum) {
```

`y+1 || z+1` evaluates to either true or false, which means the body of the `if` statement can only ever be executed, if `sum` is 0 or 1.

What you probably meant is:

```
if(y+1==sum || z+1==sum) {
```